# Converting output from database in currency format

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I have a table cell that outputs total cost. Right now it just writes it in regular number i.e 234344 I want to change it so it can display currency format i.e $3,345,1.00

```
 <td><input type="text" class="" id="totalCost"  name="totalCose" value="{{=totalCost}}" /><td/>
```

I can use solution in jquery, html or in asp.net either one. 
I tried using this jquery plugin http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/ but this works for input box while I am getting values from database. Please let me know wasted alot of time and no solution. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use.

```
    function format_num(number) {
        number += '';
        x = number.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return "$" + x1 + x2;
    }
```

So...

Input = 100000

Output = $100,000

Comment: I have mine like this using javascript. `document.getElementById("currentmoney").innerHTML = format_num(result);` So the javascript puts the value in the element with the ID of "currentmoney".